# How can I trigger a Jenkins pipeline run from a GitHub webhook and still allow manual builds?

Tags: jenkins

I am using [GitHub pull request builder](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin) to trigger pipeline builds from GitHub webhooks when developers make a PR.

To make sure I pull the pipeline script related to the PR I am using `Pipeline script from SCM` and specifying `${sha1}` as the branch specifier. The issue is that when I trigger the build manually, Jenkins is trying to pull a `${sha1}` branch (since the env variable doesn't exist).

Is there a way to default to master when triggering the build manually?

Comment: If you are triggering the build from the UI, you can specify the SHA id of the HEAD of master branch.

Comment: I guess that'd only work when building with parameters? I don't have SHA as a parameter, it comes from the webhook contents

Comment: Yes, it comes from webhook in case of pull requests. You mentioned that you want to build it manually. How do you want to trigger the build manually?

Comment: just by clicking 'Build Now'

Comment: i.e. I want to set a default for the value of sha1